# gVIM settings based on file opened, on Windows

Tags: windows, gvim

I wish to set some gVIM settings based on the file I am opening. Specifically, when I open my file `Activities.txt` I want to set the window width to 40 columns and the height to 50 rows. I believe I would use in my _vimrc file the setting

`set lines=50 columns=40`

but I was wondering how to test if I am opening the specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your .vimrc.

```
if expand("%.t") =~? 'Activities.txt'
   set lines=50 columns=40
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable modelines:

```
:set modeline
```

and put in your file, in the top or bottom 5 lines (assuming 'modelines' is set to 5):

```
 vi:set lines=50 columns=40:
```

with **at least one whitespace char** before the `vi:set`